# Sphinx automodule: how to reference classes in same module?

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am trying to use the sphinx [autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) extension and specifically the `automodule` directive to automatically generate documentation for django app I am working on. The problem is that I want to create internal references to different classes within the module, without having to use `autoclass` and `autofunction` on every single class/function within the project. For a source file like this:

```
# source_code.py
class A:
    """docs for A
    """
    pass

class B:
    """docs for B with 
    :ref:`internal reference to A <XXXX-some-reference-to-A-XXXX>`
    """
    pass
```

I would like to be able to have a sphinx documentation file like this:

```
.. automodule: source_code
```

What reference can I use for XXXX-some-reference-to-A-XXXX? Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can reference a class like this:

```
class B(object):
    """docs for B with reference to :class:`.A`"""
    pass
```

Sphinx will intelligently try and figure out what you're referencing. If there are multiple classes with the name `A`, you might get a warning, but it should pick up the one in the current module.

Answer (score 15):

Don't know if I understand the problem but this works flawlessly to me with autodoc, as per [Cross-referencing Python objects](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/domains/python.html#cross-referencing-python-objects)

```
class FlowDirection(GeneralTable):
    '''
    Heat Flow Direction
    
    :cvar int id: database primary key
    :cvar unicode name: name 
    '''
    def __repr__(self):
        return u'<FlowDirection {0} instance at {1}>'.format(
                self.name, hex(id(self))).encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class AirCavityRes(GeneralTable):
    '''
    Air Cavity :term:`thermal resistance`

    :cvar flow_direction: heat flow direction
        (see :class:`FlowDirection`)
    :cvar int id: database primary key
    :cvar int if_fd: database foreign key to :class:`FlowDirection`
    :cvar float res: :term:`thermal resistance`
    :cvar float thick: thickness
    '''
    def __repr__(self):
        return u'<AirCavityRes {0} instance at {1}>'.format(
                self.res, hex(id(self)))
```