# Toc/list with all classes generated by automodule in sphinx docs

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a python package Im about to migrate over to sphinx from epydoc. The package itself is documented with the sphinx automodule function. Now I would like to have a summary of all the classes in my module in a simple list/table in the beginning of my documented module, or even better(?) in the toc-tree.

My automodule part (in pymunk.rst) looks like

```
.. automodule:: pymunk
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
    :inherited-members:
```

then in pymunk.constraint.rst

```
.. automodule:: pymunk.constraint
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
    :inherited-members:
```

and so on. In each file I would like a list of all the classes so its easy to get an overview of whats available without scrolling through the whole documentation or the monstrous index. End result something like

```
pymunk
    pymunk.Space
    pymunk.Circle
    ...
```

My main target is to build to html.

Right now Im thinking about doing something clever with javascript to extract out and insert a list, but there must be a better way?

(The current state of the documentation: http://pymunk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pymunk.html)

Comment: Seconded, Sphinx even generates permalink anchors at each function/class/method block. See this for a hint on a hand-coded solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753805/sphinx-automodule-how-to-reference-classes-in-same-module?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery turned out to be the easy way to do this.

I added this to the raw rst file where I wanted the index:

```
.. container:: custom-index

    .. raw:: html

        <script type="text/javascript" src='_static/pymunk.js'></script>
```

This way a div is inserted into the html output so that the script can be put in all files where I wanted this index and have a header on top.

Then in pymunk.js I extracted the class, function and data tags and put into the index.

The downside with a javascript approach to this problem is that it would be hard to have a complete class index in the TOC sidebar as now it just picks the items to be included in the index from the current page. It is also a bit of work to create the index on each page load, maybe if its a big module it will feel slow in some browsers.

Full js code below:

```
$(function (){
var createList = function(selector){

    var ul = $('<ul>');
    var selected = $(selector);

    if (selected.length === 0){
        return;
    }

    selected.clone().each(function (i,e){

        var p = $(e).children('.descclassname');
        var n = $(e).children('.descname');
        var l = $(e).children('.headerlink');

        var a = $('<a>');
        a.attr('href',l.attr('href')).attr('title', 'Link to this definition');

        a.append(p).append(n);

        var entry = $('<li>').append(a);
        ul.append(entry);
    });
    return ul;
}


var c = $('<div style="float:left; min-width: 300px;">');

var ul0 = c.clone().append($('.submodule-index'))

customIndex = $('.custom-index');
customIndex.empty();
customIndex.append(ul0);

var x = [];
x.push(['Classes','dl.class > dt']);
x.push(['Functions','dl.function > dt']);
x.push(['Variables','dl.data > dt']);

x.forEach(function (e){
    var l = createList(e[1]);
    if (l) {        
        var ul = c.clone()
            .append('<p class="rubric">'+e[0]+'</p>')
            .append(l);
    }
    customIndex.append(ul);
});

});
```

Comment: In the above code, having `<div style="float:left; width:100%;">` seems necessary for getting it to display acceptably. I put the container in a file `toc.txt` and "included" it using `.. include:: toc.txt`.

Comment: I also added the line `x.push(['Exceptions','dl.exception > dt']);` for `Exception` classes.

Answer (score 2):

Sphinx now has an [autosummary extension](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.6/ext/autosummary.html) that builds summaries and toctrees based on autodoc. This way you just need to insert the following lines into your `pymunk.rst`:

```
.. currentmodule:: pymunk

.. autosummary::
   :nosignatures:

   Space
   Circle
```