# List functions in table of contents in Sphinx

Tags: templates, python-sphinx, tableofcontents

How can I list functions, classes, etc... to show up in the table of contents in Sphinx?

Or, more generally, how can I add arbitrary entries within a page (not subtitles) to the table of contents?

BTW: I'm not documenting Python code, so I can't use the autodoc tools.

**Edit**

I tried the directive `.. contents:: name`, but that seems to be for placing a ToC, not defining an entry.

**Edit: Partial Solution**

I copied the `basic/localtoc.html` template to my `_templates` directory.

`{{ pagename }}` gives the path to the current file and `{% include filename %}` lets me include a file, so I could presumably combine those, and just generate my own Table of Contents for every file whenever `conf.py` is run. I will try this, but is there a more automatic solution?

Comment: I could also generate my own and include by setting the `html_sidebars` variable, but that places content after the navigation and before the search. I'd like it to be on top. (Actually: I think I'd like the search on top, then the contents.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating lots of individual templates, one can create a single template that uses javascript to populate extra entries on the table of contents at load time.

I can use viblo's script from [Toc/list with all classes generated by automodule in sphinx docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150491/toc-list-with-all-classes-generated-by-automodule-in-sphinx-docs) that dynamically generates lists of `Classes`, `Functions`, and `Variables`.

My `_templates/localtoc.html` then becomes:

```js
<h3><a href="{{ pathto(master_doc) }}">{{ _('Table Of Contents') }}</a></h3>
{%- if display_toc %}

  {{ toc }}
{%- endif %}
<div class="custom-index container">
<script type="text/javascript" src={{ pathto(master_doc)[:-10] + '_static/pymunk.js' }}></script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to group members into public and private sections in the API documentation, so I want them to appear inside the TOC hierarchy. I adapted @viblo's and @ramcdougal's solutions to achieve this.

Here's my `_static/apitoc.js`:

```js
// Inject API members into the TOC in the sidebar.
// This should be loaded in the localtoc.html template.

$(function (){
    $('div.section').each(function(index) {
        var $section = $(this),
            $tocitem = $('.sphinxlocaltoc li:has(> a.reference.internal[href="#' + 
                         $section.attr('id') +
                         '"])');
            $members = $('<ul>').appendTo($tocitem);
        $('> dl > dt', $section).each(function(index) {
            var $member = $(this),
                $tocMember = $('<li class="api-member">');
            $tocMember.text($('.property', $member).text() + ' ');
            $tocMember.append('<a href="#' + $member.attr('id') + '">' + 
                              $('.descname', $member).text() + 
                              '</a>');
            $members.append($tocMember);
        });
    });
});
```

And here's `_templates/localtoc.html`:

```js
<h3><a href="{{ pathto(master_doc) }}">{{ _('Table Of Contents') }}</a></h3>
{%- if display_toc %}
  {{ toc }}
  <div class="custom-index container">
    <script type="text/javascript" src={{ pathto(master_doc)[:-10] + '_static/apitoc.js' }}></script>
  </div>
{%- endif %}
```

The result looks like:

---

#### Page contents

mypackage.mymodule

- Public API

  - class [MyPublicClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342056/list-functions-in-table-of-contents-in-sphinx)
  - class [AnotherPublicClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342056/list-functions-in-table-of-contents-in-sphinx)
  - [my_public_function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342056/list-functions-in-table-of-contents-in-sphinx)
- Private API

  - class [MyPrivateClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342056/list-functions-in-table-of-contents-in-sphinx)
  - [my_private_function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342056/list-functions-in-table-of-contents-in-sphinx)